# Android Facebook SDK 3.0: Simple way to get user token (no session needed)

Tags: android, facebook

I only need to get the user's FB token with certain permissions. I will then send it to my server. Everything else is done from there. I don't need cached tokens or anything. The SDK can make a full check on every attempt and it also should, to make sure that the user has not revoked access to my app, although the token might not have expired.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Do you have the answer to this question now?